# Bash for truncation

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have to make changes to a document where there are two columns separated by tab (\t) and each record separated by newline \n. the statements of the document are as follows:

```
  /something/random/2345.txt
```

my aim is to remove the entire string and just keep the number 2345 in this case.I used

```
 sed 's/something/random//g' file.csv
```

but I do not know how to escape the / cause sed syntax has / too. Also not all records have the same words so i would be looking for regex of the type

```
  /*/*.*
```

But each entry has a number as a part of the record and I would like to extract that.
Also there are a few records which do not contain any number, I would like to delete those records along with the corresponding entry in the next column for that record.
The file is in CSV format.

Comment: Your regex is weird, do you mean that as a wildcard? `sed -n 's%^/[^/]*/\([^/.]*\)\.[^/]*$%\1%p' file.csv` might Do What You Mean ... Although that wants a different number of slashes than your actual example.

Comment: Please post several completed lines of your CSV file

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the forward slash with a backslash, or you can use a different character than forward slash to delimit your expression. Observe:

```
echo foobar | sed sIfooIcrowI
> crowbar
```

Of course, you probably shouldn't use an alphabetic character for the delimiter. I'm just using it here to make the point that pretty much any normal character can be substituted for the slash.

Comment: @tripleee yeah i should probably mention that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove all non digit characters from brining of each statement in string :

```
   sed 's/[^0-9]*\(.*\)[\t]*/\1/g'
```